# How do I hide a method from a superclass?

Tags: ruby

I have a method in a superclass from a third-party gem which I want to hide. I would prefer if it is impossible to call this method at all, so not just override it and leave the body empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this may be what you're looking for:

```
undef_method :foo
```

This will prevent any calls to the method `foo`.

In contrast, this will not achieve the same effect:

```
remove_method :foo
```

That will remove the method from the child, but will still pass through up the inheritance chain.

Docs: [undef_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/undef_method) and [remove_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/remove_method)

Comment: Actually it is hard to choose the "correct answer" in this case. I like this way because it is more concise and I don't have to write a delegate for all those functions I want to use (which are quite a few) but I think in some cases it is better to use the answer from Sergio Tulentsev

Answer (score 3):

Use the `undef` keyword.

```
class A
  def foo
    5
  end
end

class B < A
  undef foo
end

A.new.foo #=> 5
B.new.foo #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

That is wrong OOP that you're trying to do there. I suggest you use composition instead of inheritance.

```
require 'forwardable' 

class SomeBaseClass
  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end

  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end

  def quux
    puts 'quux'
  end
end

class MyClass

  def initialize
    @base = SomeBaseClass.new
  end

  extend Forwardable

  def_delegators :@base, :foo, :bar # but not quux
end

mc = MyClass.new

mc.foo
mc.bar
mc.quux

# >> foo
# >> bar
# ~> -:32:in `<main>': undefined method `quux' for #<MyClass:0x007febcc155210> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: That's a very interesting design pattern. Haven't seen it before. Do you happen to know why there exists an `undef` keyword, when this is the better way of doing this?

Comment: @Nessuno: Because Ruby is very flexible. And "better" is subjective. :)